# How to debug Code Engine build errors (Dockerfile strategy)?

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud, container-image, ibm-cloud-code-engine

I am using IBM Cloud Code Engine. Building the container locally, pushing it to the IBM Container Registry and then creating the Code Engine app from it works. Now, I wanted to build the container image using Code Engine. The code is in a public GitHub repository. I am using the build strategy "Dockerfile" based on this [Dockerfile](https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/cloud-sql-database/blob/ce/Dockerfile).

When I submit a build using the console, it fails after a while and I see these lines in the output.

```
#13 1.368 Collecting ibm_db>=3.0.2
#13 1.374   Downloading ibm_db-3.1.2.tar.gz (1.1 MB)
#13 1.381      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1.1/1.1 MB 234.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#13 1.711   Installing build dependencies: started
#13 5.425   Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
#13 5.430   Getting requirements to build wheel: started
#13 6.751   Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
#13 6.752 ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/tmpqm5wa7sq/output.json'
```

How can I investigate this further? Could the errors be from different tools creating the container image? How would I proceed?

Comment: Add your public git url with pointer to Dockerfile to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several options on how to approach the issue:

- First and most important: [Obtain and check the logs for anything suspicious](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/codeengine?topic=codeengine-troubleshoot-build). The logs are available in the Code Engine browser console for the buildruns, or via command line:

  ```
  ibmcloud ce buildrun logs --name mybuildrun
  ```
- In addition, there is extra information on the buildrun by using either

  ```
  ibmcloud ce buildrun get --name mybuildrun
  ```

  or

  ```
  ibmcloud ce buildrun events --name mybuildrun
  ```
- On a new GitHub branch or better locally, modify the Dockerfile and add extra steps to access files of interest or print additional debugging output. The latter could be done be adding `|| cat /some/log/file` to a failing step.
- Make sure that all requirements and packages that are installed are correct and available.
- Check the dependencies for known issues.

In the case that lead to my question I needed more debug output to find an issue with a broken software module from my requirements.txt.